# Unique Yahoo Handle

Tags: api, email, oauth, yahoo

Is it possible to get a human-readable and **unique** handle to a Yahoo's account using their APIs? (after authenticating with OAuth)

From what I've gathered so far, I know that getting a user's email address is not possible.
Is there any way of getting the user's Yahoo ID then? Or any unique name that I could use to identify Yahoo users.

Currently I can only get the user's first name, last name, and their nickname.
None of which are guaranteed to be unique.
There's the GUID too, but it's not human-readable..

I've tried asking twice at Yahoo's developer forums, but it seems to be dead..
Anything I could do?

Thank you!